# Deploy com Capistrano - Comando su

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, deploy, amazon-aws

Estou usando o capistrano para deploy na Amazon.

Capistrano + Unicorn + Nginx + Ec2

Quando vou fazer o deploy:cold, ele dá o seguinte erro:

```
 servers: ["ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com"]
[ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com] executing command
[err :: ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com] su: must be run from a terminal
failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell '2.1.0' -c '/etc/init.d/unicorn_app      start'" on ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

O problema é que ele tenta usar o comando SU no arquivo unicorn_init.sh.
Pesquisei muito e não consigo progredir. Alguém tem ideia de uma possível solução?

Comment: que gems está a usar para o capistrano? Em caso de estar a seguir algum tutorial também ajudava saber qual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenda dar permissão de execução ao arquivo `chmod +x unicorn_init.sh`, pode ser isso.

Ou então, você está rodando ele como "root"? pode ser preciso: `sudo ./unicorn_init.sh`

Comment: Fábio, não tem como pois tudo é feito pelo capistrano. Ele que envia os arquivos necessários para o server.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar o user que faz o deploy na lista de `sudoers` (via `sudo visudo`) de forma que ele possa fazer `sudo` sem precisar que a senha do root seja digitada, e passar a usar `sudo` ao invés de `su`.

Tome cuidado e limite o escopo do script de forma que ele só consiga executar processos específicos como sudo. P.ex:

```
#/etc/sudoers
deploy ALL=NOPASSWD:/etc/init.d/mysqld, /etc/init.d/apache2
```

Comment: Rodrigo, tentei dessa forma e nada. Meu usuário já tinha permissão de sudo. Esse SU está dentro do unicorn_init.sh. Tentei mudar lá para sudo e deu erro. Acho que ele precisa desse SU mesmo. Não entendo muito dessa config do unicorn.